# Can't connect to server via mosh

Tags: ssh, server, debian, client-server, mosh

I started the server on `Debian`, installed all the necessary settings and connected the `SSH key`. I connect to the server:

```
ssh -i yandex_key rhost@51.250.1.155
```

Terminal output:

```
Linux rhost 4.19.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.208-1 (2021-09-29) x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Mon Nov  8 12:56:48 2021 from 31.181.120.181
```

I run a `mosh-server` on the server:

```
mosh-server (mosh 1.3.2) [build mosh 1.3.2]
Copyright 2012 Keith Winstein <mosh-devel@mit.edu>
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

[mosh-server detached, pid = 1739]
```

I go back to my local machine and run the `mosh-client`:

```
mosh-client (mosh 1.3.2) [build mosh 1.3.2]
Copyright 2012 Keith Winstein <mosh-devel@mit.edu>
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Usage: mosh-client [-# 'ARGS'] IP PORT
       mosh-client -c
```

I run the command in the terminal:

```
MOSH_KEY=YfK...qoQ mosh-client 51.250.1.155 60001
```

return:

```
mosh did not make a successful connection to 51.250.1.155:60001.
Please verify that UDP port 60001 is not firewalled and can reach the server.

(By default, mosh uses a UDP port between 60000 and 61000. The -p option
selects a specific UDP port number.)
[mosh is exiting.]
```

I try to connect using other commands `mosh [rhost@]51.250.1.155` `mosh rhost@51.250.1.155`, there is no result. I contacted server support but they said the problem was on my side. What could be the problem? I need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have UDP ports 60000-61000 open in your firewall.

Comment: This may help someone else -- if you're using `ufw` for a firewall:

`sudo ufw allow 60001/udp`

[1] https://github.com/mobile-shell/mosh/issues/1039#issuecomment-998655769